# How to split string in multiple column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have string "1:182:1,1:195:2,1:213:1".
I spllited the string with ',' in different rows. Now I want each rows single column to be splitted in 3 different columns in same row.

I tried using

```
     SELECT   LEFT(ThemeProperty, CHARINDEX(':', ThemeProperty) - 1) ,
            RIGHT(ThemeProperty,
                  LEN(ThemeProperty) - CHARINDEX(':', ThemeProperty))
   FROM     #tempThemeProperty
```

But its output is 

`(No column name)    (No column name)
1                     182:1
1                     195:2
1                     213:1`

But I want it to be

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
1       182     1
```

So any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just use second charindex to find the second :

Comment: is your problem solved from above answer

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @Tmp TABLE (Id INT,Name VARCHAR(20)) 
INSERT @Tmp SELECT 1,'182:1' 
INSERT @Tmp SELECT 2,'195:2' 
INSERT @Tmp SELECT 3,'213:1' 


--Using PARSENAME 

SELECT Id, 
       PARSENAME(REPLACE(Name,':','.'),2) Value1, 
       PARSENAME(REPLACE(Name,':','.'),1) Value2 
FROM @Tmp
```

This should be able to di it.. Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

This is one method but subject to sql injection

```
declare @s varchar(2000),@data varchar(2000)

select @s='1:182:1'

select @data=''''+replace(@s,':',''',''')+'''' 

exec('select '+@data)
```